# Silverstripe 3.1 Change the default button text of the Gridfield Add button?

Tags: silverstripe

How do I change the default button text of the `Gridfield` Add button?
I guess it's something to do with `->getConfig()` , any ideas?

Comment: Is this getting closer?  getConfig()->getComponentsByType('GridFieldAddNewButton')->setButtonName('Add Extra Product Gallery Images')

Comment: I think it is. There is just one "s" to much.
$gridField->getConfig()->getComponentByType('GridFieldAddNewButton')->setButtonName('Add Extra Product Gallery Images');

Comment: You might also just define the private static $singular_name and $plural_name in your Dataobjects, as the "add" button takes this by default.

Comment: Great thanks, both these answers work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the default button text of the Gridfield Add button by one of the following examples:

```
//$gridfield = ..... // define you gridfield as normal first...then
$gridfield->getConfig()->getComponentByType('GridFieldAddNewButton')->setButtonName('Add Extra Product Gallery Images');
```

OR add this to your dataobject:

```
static $singular_name = "Add Extra Product Gallery Image";
static $plural_name = "Add Extra Product Gallery Images";
```

Comment: Hi @user3257693, it's great to see you solved your problem and thanks for sharing the solution. Could you mark your answer as accepted so people can easily see that this problem was solved?